# Which of these is more python-like?

Tags: python

I'm doing some exploring of various languages I hadn't used before, using a simple Perl script as a basis for what I want to accomplish.  I have a couple of versions of something, and I'm curious which is the preferred method when using Python -- or if  neither is, what is?

Version 1:

```
workflowname = []
paramname = []
value = []
for line in lines:
        wfn, pn, v = line.split(",")
        workflowname.append(wfn)
        paramname.append(pn)
        value.append(v)
```

Version 2:

```
workflowname = []
paramname = []
value = []
i = 0;
for line in lines:
        workflowname.append("")
        paramname.append("")
        value.append("")
        workflowname[i], paramname[i], value[i] = line.split(",")
        i = i + 1
```

Personally, I prefer the second, but, as I said, I'm curious what someone who really knows Python would prefer.

Comment: The second one is less performant than the first. Also the first is more *pythonic* in my opinion, the latter is even **unpythonic** i think.

Comment: In general the less lines the better

Comment: They're all potentially terrible.  Why are you separating these things that arrived together in the input file?

Comment: In general, number of lines is irrelevant, what counts is how long it takes the reader to understand the code fully. If that takes more lines, so be it. First is better here on all scores. Second sucks hard. Loop counter? If you really want one of those (you don't) use enumerate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bogdan's answer is best. In general, if you need a loop counter (which you don't in this case), you should use `enumerate` instead of incrementing a counter:

```
for index, value in enumerate(lines):
    # do something with the value and the index
```

Comment: Okay, yeah, that does everything I need.

Comment: I mean, I wouldn't recommend using this code. @bogdan's is better in every way. Good luck anyway...!

Comment: ... the `enumerate()` is totally unnecessary because the index isn't being used to do anything useful :(

Comment: -1: Loop counters are not very Pythonic to begin with.  They're rarely useful.  This is a particularly bad piece of coding.  While it works, it's bizarre.

Comment: Right, I should just change the answer so that it points out the existence of `enumerate`, which is *sometimes* useful, and not present it as a solution to the problem here, which it was not intended to be.

Answer (score 14):

A Pythonic solution might a bit like @Bogdan's, but using zip and argument unpacking

```
workflowname, paramname, value = zip(*[line.split(',') for line in lines])
```

If you're determined to use a for construct, though, the 1st is better.

Answer (score 4):

Of your two attepts the 2nd one doesn't make any sense to me. Maybe in other languages it would. So from your two proposed approaces the 1st one is better.

Still I think the pythonic way would be something like Matt Luongo suggested.

Comment: I'd like that, but it doesn't allow me to save away the data for later parsing.  And while in this particular case, I don't do a lot of work in the second pass, in other cases I do.  Sometimes I need to run multiple passes through the data to get the exact information I need.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by 'save away the data for later parsing'. I agree this can't be user in any situation but in your case and even in more complex situations it's still the 'pythonic' way to go imo.

Comment: @Matt Luongo it sure works in mine TT. What input did you try for lines? Keep in mind that if OP question would work than you can assume an input of the form:   lines = ['1,2,3', '4,5,6', '7,8,9']

Comment: Or, to look at it another way- shouldn't `workflowname` be `['1','4','7']` after your code, and not `['1','2','3']`?

Comment: @Sean: "it doesn't allow me to save away the data for later parsing"?  Are you asking where the `append` methods wenn?    The `append` methods are still required.  They're just not repeated here.

Comment: Yea you're right just picked horrible input and forgot that you actually get a list of 3-element tuples instead of a tuple of 3 lists. My bad :D

Answer (score 1):

Version 1 is definitely better than version 2 (why put something in a list if you're just going to replace it?) but depending on what you're planning to do later, neither one may be a good idea. Parallel lists are almost never more convenient than lists of objects or tuples, so I'd consider:

```
# list of (workflow,paramname,value) tuples
items = []
for line in lines:
    items.append( line.split(",") )
```

Or:

```
class WorkflowItem(object):
    def __init__(self,workflow,paramname,value):
        self.workflow = workflow
        self.paramname = paramname
        self.value = value

# list of objects
items = []
for line in lines:
    items.append( WorkflowItem(*line.split(",")) )
```

(Also, nitpick: 4-space tabs are preferable to 8-space.)